# How can I update the data in 6 Kendo UI Dropdown List boxes

Tags: kendo-ui

I have six KendoUI Dropdown list boxes.  How do I invoke an event to update the data in each dropdown box from our database, for all list boxes when one of the boxes value is changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! You don't need to update one by one but you can define and `ObservableObject` that you update with the data from your database and get all updated.

For simplicity, I'm going to define also in the the `ObservableObject` the DataSource of each of the `DropDownList`. What I have is:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    data : [
        [ "text_1_1", "text_1_2", "text_1_3", "text_1_4" ],
        [ "text_2_1", "text_2_2", "text_2_3", "text_2_4" ],
        [ "text_3_1", "text_3_2", "text_3_3", "text_3_4" ],
        [ "text_4_1", "text_4_2", "text_4_3", "text_4_4" ],
        [ "text_5_1", "text_5_2", "text_5_3", "text_5_4" ],
        [ "text_6_1", "text_6_2", "text_6_3", "text_6_4" ]
    ],
    value: [
        "text_1_3", "text_2_2", "text_3_1", "text_4_1", "text_5_2", "text_6_3"
    ]
});
```

And then I bind it to an HTML element that contains all the `DropDownList`.

```
kendo.bind($("#dropdown-all"), viewModel);
```

The HTML is:

```
<div id="dropdown-all">
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: data[0], value: value[0]"></select>
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: data[1], value: value[1]"></select>
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: data[2], value: value[2]"></select>
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: data[3], value: value[3]"></select>
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: data[4], value: value[4]"></select>
    <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: data[5], value: value[5]"></select>
</div>
```

Now, if you want to update all the values, you should do:

```
viewModel.set("value", [
    "text_1_4", "text_2_4", "text_3_4", "text_4_4", "text_5_4", "text_6_4"
]);
```

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ac5nF/

Answer (score 0):

Just bind them all with the same datasource which is updated by a server call.
Whatever happens in that one daatasource, will affect every element 'bound' to it.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-dataSource

Comment: I understand that, but each DropDownList has different data which is returned from the Controller ?

Comment: If you have different dataSources for each dropDown, you have to manually observe the dataBound event of each, and when one of them fires, just trigger 'read' to the other dataSources as well.